# Getting ServerWebExchange in RestController method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

How can I get `ServerWebExchange` or reactive `ServerHttpResponse` in controller method?

I'm constantly getting `NestedServletException` while trying to call rest controller method that accepts `ServerWebExchange`.

My controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/path/{param1}/path", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class MyController {
    @GetMapping("/path")
    public Mono<Void> method(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Main method:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"my.package1", "my.package2"})
@EnableWebFlux
public class MyApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Exception:

> io.undertow.request                      : UT005023: Exception handling request to /path/value/path/path
>
> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No primary or default constructor found for interface org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Solution*: Make sure you have no `spring-webmvc` on classpath.

I was migrating to `spring-webflux`, but got `spring-webmvc` as a transitive dependency. `webflux` and `webmvc` are incompatible - only one would handle requests.